# Android: Youtube Search Application for given Word

Tags: android, search, youtube

I want to create a android search application that can be used to search a video from youtube for given word.

how do I do that. please someone give me a tutorial link. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try the below code .

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
intent.putExtra("query", "Android");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks but it gives following error :android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEARCH flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.google.android.youtube (has extras) }

Comment: are you trying it in emulator ?

Comment: Please try it in device as YouTube application is not installed in emulator.

Answer (score 3):

use this API for Searching a Video on Youtube

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=india

where q is word you want to search related videos

for more detail see [YouTube APIs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started#data_api)